# AllowHtml in property allow my users to break page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I use tinyMCE to allow users to stylize text in text areas.
I have a property

```
[AllowHtml] Description {get;set;}
```

And everything works fine. But if use write something like this:

```
<div>not closed tag
```

This break my whole page. How to prevent this situation?
I use this to display text:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Description)
```

Comment: Cannot express how dangerous this is. Do not allow your users to dump in raw html.

Comment: But I must do this :) I use tiny mce to allow users to make bold, italic text, list, bullets. But if some bad guy enter `<div>ss` and save this make a large issue for me and must find some solution. I know for sure that if someonw enter `<script>alert(x);</script>` doesn't save to database. Just unclosed tag make trouble.

Comment: And what if someone used an `iframe` with a `src` that loaded script? Or perhaps `</body>` or `</html>` or a number of other random things that could break the page.

Comment: And how stackoverflow allow this? I can left unclosed tags in my question and don't break anything.

Comment: Stackoverflow, and StackExchange in general, does not use `Html.Raw`, nor `AllowHtml`. User input is scrubbed and symbols are used to represent bold, italic, code blocks, etc.

Comment: Any link or tutorial how can I make the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AllowHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is only going to permit certain special characters to be posted. This will not validate your markup.

> If a property is marked with the AllowHtmlAttribute attribute, the ASP.NET MVC framework skips validation for that property during model binding

It can be a security issue loading user generated markup onto the page. Your validator would want to strip out certain tags like `script.` Many sites use an iframe to show user generated markup content to avoid this issue.